# how to move this logic from a controller to a factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple UI where a user can enter multiple values using an input field. Those values are displayed in a list using ng-model and ng-repeat. My current controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope){
   "use strict";
   $scope.items = [];
   $scope.recordTemperature = function(){
     $scope.items.push({
       temperature: $scope.newTemperature
     });
     // Clear input fields after push
     $scope.newTemperature = '';
   };    
});
```

This controller currently works so, I wanted to start creating more methods but
I'd like to move the recordTemperature to a factory since I'll be adding more methods and wanted to keep my controller clean.
So I figure I could change my controller to be:

```
.controller('mainController','TemperatureMonitor', function($scope, TemperatureMonitor){
  "use strict";
  $scope.addTemperature = function(){
    if($scope.myForm.$valid){
      TemperatureMonitor.recordTemperature();
    }else{
      alert('invalid form');
    }
  };
});
```

and my factory something like this:

```
.factory('TemperatureMonitor', function(){
  $scope.items = [];
  return{
    recordTemperature: function(){
      $scope.items.push({
        temperature: $scope.newTemperature
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm having a hard time seeing the answer, I've tried several things, too many to list ;) without success :(
Thanks for any help.
Here's the HTML for reference:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
    <h1>Temperature Monitor</h1>
    <form ng-submit='submitted=true; recordTemperature();' name="myForm">
      <label for="temperature">Add Temperture:</label>
      <input name="temperature" id="temperature" ng-model="newTemperature">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="startOver">Start over</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.temperature}}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Services don't have a $scope (and even if they had one you would have to inject it, as is controllers). Just use `var items = []`. Do you realize, though, that a service is a singleton? This means that if you navigate to another page and come back to this controller, you'll find back the old items in the service?

Comment: cool, thanks JB. yes I'm totally aware about the service being a singleton and the issues about navigating to other pages. Not worry too much about that single this is just a single page app I'm doing just for practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope` is a local injectable only available to controllers and usually (but not always) different for each instantiation of a controller.

To make the function work, you need to pass $scope objects to factory service functions as parameters of that function.

**Your factory**:

```
.factory('TemperatureMonitor', function(){
  return{
    recordTemperature: function(items,newTemperature){
      items.push({
        temperature: newTemperature
      });
    }
  };
})
```

**Your controller**:

```
.controller('mainController','TemperatureMonitor', function($scope, TemperatureMonitor){
  "use strict";
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.addTemperature = function($scope.items, $scope.newTemperature){
    if($scope.myForm.$valid){
      TemperatureMonitor.recordTemperature();
    }else{
      alert('invalid form');
    }
  };
});
```

As mentioned by in a comment by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet), factory services are **singletons**. Any data in them are shared between instantiations of controllers and persist throughout the entire lifetime of the application.

Comment: there may be an issue by using: $scope.items, $scope.newTemperature in the function. Got an error with invalid syntax